# Applying double color transform in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, colors

Simply put, I would like to set several movieclips to different specific colors and then apply a tint over them.

```
var color1 = new ColorTransform(); color1.color = 0x0000FF;
var color2 = new ColorTransform(); color2.color = 0x00FF00;
var color3 = new ColorTransform(); color3.color = 0xFFFF00;

thing1.transform.colorTransform = color1;
thing2.transform.colorTransform = color2;
thing3.transform.colorTransform = color3;

thing1.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 200, 150, 0);
thing2.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 200, 150, 0);
thing3.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 200, 150, 0);
```

unfortunately the colortransform resets the value. Any way to keep the value of the first color transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution to this problem.

If I set an object to a color

```
var color1 = new ColorTransform(); color1.color = 0x0000FF;
thing1.transform.colorTransform = color1;
```

I can then edit the blue and green values as so to get my desired tint

```
color1.blueOffset+=200;
color1.greenOffset+=150;
```

And then use colortransform on the object to set the new color

```
thing1.transform.colorTransform = color1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do that with the [ColorTransform.concat()](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html#concat()) function.

```
var color1 = new ColorTransform(); color1.color = 0x0000FF;
var color2 = new ColorTransform(); color2.color = 0x00FF00;
var color3 = new ColorTransform(); color3.color = 0xFFFF00;

color1.concat( new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 200, 150, 0) );
color2.concat( new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 200, 150, 0) );
color3.concat( new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 200, 150, 0) );

thing1.transform.colorTransform = color1;
thing2.transform.colorTransform = color2;
thing3.transform.colorTransform = color3;
```

Which essentially is the same as (clamping offset values to 255 using `Math.min`):

```
thing1.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(1*1, 1*1, 1*1, 1*1, Math.min(0x00+0, 0xFF), Math.min(0x00+200, 0xFF), Math.min(0xFF+150, 0xFF), Math.min(0x00+0, 0xFF));
thing2.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(1*1, 1*1, 1*1, 1*1, Math.min(0x00+0, 0xFF), Math.min(0xFF+200, 0xFF), Math.min(0x00+150, 0xFF), Math.min(0x00+0, 0xFF));
thing3.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(1*1, 1*1, 1*1, 1*1, Math.min(0xFF+0, 0xFF), Math.min(0xFF+200, 0xFF), Math.min(0x00+150, 0xFF), Math.min(0x00+0, 0xFF));
```

Or:

```
thing1.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, 0x00, 0xC8, 0xFF, 0x00);
thing2.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x96, 0x00);
thing3.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(1, 1, 1, 1, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x96, 0x00);
```

Comment: although its not throwing an error, its not applying the concat color change

Comment: Can you verify that `color3` has changed its `blueOffset` from 0 to 150 after calling `concat`?

Comment: i copied your code exactly, there is no other code in the file and it has not changed the blueoffset of any of the movieclips